# understanding shceme field lines - magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I would like to know if the magnetic field is in "the x-y plane". Does this mean the field lines are actually parallel to the visible line x or y? Or does it mean the field lines are parallel to the z-axis and crossing the x-y plane?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. "In the XY plane" means "perpendicular to the Z axis". It doesn't mean they are either parallel to X or Y - it could be at 45° to either of these axes.

The equation of a plane is sometimes written as

$$(\vec{x} - \vec{x_0})\cdot \vec{n} = 0$$

Where $\vec{x}$ is any point on the plane, $\vec{x_0}$ is a known point on the plane, and $\vec{n}$ is the normal to the plane (in this case, the Z axis). That expression basically shows that any vector in the XY plane is perpendicular to Z (since the dot product is zero).

Comment: The drawing in the OP is troubling though.

Comment: @gonenc - I agree. Looking closely, I think that $B_0$ is in the XY plane, with $Z$ sticking out of the page. It shows the $X$ component of the $B$ field...